# Hyperledger Indy - VON-network error - Error initializing pool ledger

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, hyperledger-aries

I am trying to run von-network on using docker. These are the steps that i followed.

1. Clone `von-network` repo form https://github.com/bcgov/von-network
2. Ran `./manage build`
3. Then `./manage start --logs`
   At this point all the docker containers starts OK. But when i go `http://localhost:9000`, in my browser, i see error saying, `Error initializing pool ledger`.
   [image]

But actually, I should be getting this:
[image]

I have tried this many times. Also tried deleting all the images and redoing everything from scratch, but get the same errors.
An exception is logged on the terminal (shown in the screenshot),
[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors for nodes? or error is only in server? Looks like there is a problem with genesis and webserver is not able to reach nodes because of incorect GENESIS_URL

Comment: I don;t know the exact cause, but after deleting my VM and creating a new VM, now it works.

Comment: Hi Sir,
I received the same error.
May I know the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Pool ledger timeout mostly occurs when the genesis.txn file is deformed or not found, you should check the pool_cfg path, and make sure it is directed at the genesis.txn file